# change numbers from 13,800,000 to 13.8M or 197,000 to 197K

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to have a currency field convert from...

example:

13,800,000 to 13.8M or 197,000 to 197K

I have tried to use totext and cstr but I get...

13.80M and 1.97K

```
`if totext({currencyfield},"0000000") >= "1000000" then
 totext({currencyfield}/1000000) + "M" 
 else if totext({currencyfield},"000000") <= "999999" then
 totext({currencyfield}/100000) + "K" else
 totext({currencyfield});`
```

Using the example above, my `{currencyfield}` = $197,015.00 and using this formula, I get $1.97K but I need to get $197K.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: k = 1000, so you should divide by `1000`, not `100000`.

Comment: Thank you, Klas.

That helped a little and now I get $197.00K. Still have 2 decimal places in a ToText that I need to suppress or truncate but within the formula above.

Comment: Use this totext(value,'#')

Comment: Thank you, Siva but your suggestion did the same thing. I still get $197.00K.

Comment: Crystal Reports probably tries to format with 2 decimals because it is a currency field. Try converting it to a regular number before converting it to text.

Comment: Thank you, Klas. Unfortunately, that also does not work. I still get the decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula and code as per seperation :

```
If {tabe.field} >= 1000000 then
totext({table.number}/1000000,1,"") +" million"
else If {tabe.field} >= 100000 then
totext({table.number}/100000,1,"") +" hundred thousand"
else If {tabe.field} >= 1000 then
totext({table.number}/1000,1,"") +" thousand"
else If {tabe.field} >= 100 then
totext({table.number}/100,1,"") +" hundred"
```

Please check this link :

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=854759

https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/customized-thousand-separator-in-crystal-report/

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=457612&sid=225d1ca884d4a615bc971c414afbdc23

Comment: Thank you, Ajay2707! This did the trick. However, If the currency field prior to changing it to text is a negative, how can I enter * -1 at the end?

`If {currencyfield} <= -1000000 then 
totext({currencyfield}/-100000,1,"") +"M"
else If {currencyfield} >= -999999 and {currencyfield} <= -100000 then
totext(currencyfield/-1000,0,"") +"K"
else totext(currencyfield,0,",");` Where to enter * -1?

Comment: NM - got it - Thank you, Ajay2707!